# Why would a meteor shower have 2 areas of origination and 2 directions of travel?

Tags: meteor-shower

I watched for the herculid shower last night and saw several. There were 2 general areas of activity in the sky. I would place them at 11 o'clock and 2 o'clock with 12 directly over head. 1/2 the streaks traveled south to north and 1/2 west to east. Both areas of origination had streaks in both directions. This is not what I expected. How does this happen?

Comment: Meteor showers have a radiant, where the meteors appear to be coming from, but they will go in every direction from that radiant.  It's also more common than not that showers overlap with each other, so there is more than one radiant.  And, in addition to that, there are also random meteors not associated with any radiant.